# Selenium : Make chrome browser window hide for a while till login

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, selenium

I am using Selenium for chrome browser automation(OS-windows only). I want to open a webpage and fill a login form , submit.But i dont want to show this login page(chrome browser) to the user.That is user will not see the chrome window which shows filling the form and clicking submit. The user must be able to see chrome only after clicking submit(which i click in my code). So i need to hide the chrome(only this window,but if user has kept some other chrome window open they should not be made visible false) for a while and then after login i want to make chrome window visible.

Below is a part of code in which chrome browser opens with login page and form filled automatically and submit is clicked and new page navigated(after login)

```
Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
Dim driver1 As ChromeDriver = Nothing
Dim driver As EventFiringWebDriver
Dim chromeOptions As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("ignore-certifcate-errors")
chromeOptions.AddArgument("test-type")
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
driver1 = New ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions)
driver = New EventFiringWebDriver(driver1)
AddHandler driver.Navigated, AddressOf OnNavigated

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/login.htm")
Dim myLink1 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("userName"))
myLink1.SendKeys("myusername")
Dim myLink2 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"))
myLink2.SendKeys("mypassword")
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='submit']")).Click()
```

So now can I make the chrome window to not visible till login and then make it visisble in selenium or is there any other trick where I can achieve the same.

Comment: If you don't want to see the browser then you will need to invest in headless browsers. Anything else is going to be an extremely hacky, ugly and unreliable way to hide a window and could potentially cause issues later on.

Comment: Is this suppose to fulfill some kind of security requirement?